# Sharing model definitions across platforms

Tags: android, ios

I’m not sure how to put this on a title, here is the long explanation:

I share some application logic between iOS and Android (both are implemented on their own native language, no cross platform) mainly analytics and firebase remote config models. Since analytics names, attributes and value types should be consistent across platforms I have to double check both analytics models on iOS and Android very carefully.

Is there a service/method/convention I can use to keep the consistency of these models across platforms?